# UIProgressView unprogressed color

Tags: iphone, uiprogressview

I have a `UIProgressView` which I want to look like this image. I have set the progress color but I am not sure to set unprogressed color (white color in image).

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here is the simple solution I myself found on exploring properties for UIProgressView :

```
progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me !!

Comment: Works perfects..